# Java EE realm with BaseX?

Tags: java, database, jakarta-ee, realm, basex

I'm developing a Web application on Java EE with BaseX as Database System.
In the Web application I need an user authentification and would like to store the informations in a BaseX collection like the one below:

```
    <user>myUser</user>
    <password>myPassword</password>
    <roles>
        <role>myRole1</role>
        <role>myRole2</role>
    </roles>
```

Is it possible to use a realm on a BaseX collection?

**Note:** I can't use tomcat-users.xml or an LDAP authentification server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find anything existing and so i created my own custom realm to use the user authentification and store the users in a BaseX collection.

You can find it under my Github account:

https://github.com/michelsahli/BaseXRealm